# Блок с изображение и текстом под

Tags: html, css

Хотел такое сделать подскажите что не так?

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

```css
 .project-info {
    position: absolute;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    background-image: url("../../img/phone.png");
    display: flex;
    background-position: center;
    background-size: cover;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    justify-content: center;
    -ms-align-items: center;
    align-items: center;
    opacity: 1;
}
    
.project-subinfo {
    width: 370px;
    height: 100%;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    background-color: #fbfaf8;
    display: flex;
    text-align: center;
    flex-direction: column;
}

.project-subinfo__title {
    color: #1a2940;
    display: block;
    font-size: 18px;
    text-align: center;
}
    
.project-subinfo__subtitle {
    color: #1a2940;
    display: block;
    font-size: 18px;
    text-align: center;
    margin-top: 10px;
}
```

```html
<div class="project-item first">
    <div class="project-info">

    </div>
</div>
<div class="project-subinfo">
    <span class="project-subinfo__title">
     Claritas Etiam Processus
    </span>
    <span  class="project-subinfo__subtitle">
     Photography, Nature
    </span>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Идеально вам подходит вот это :

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

figure {
  width: 35%;
  text-align: center;
  font-style: italic;
  font-size: smaller;
  border: thin silver solid;
  margin:20px;
}

figcaption {
  font-size: 1.4em;
  position: relative;
  padding: 20px;
}

img.scaled {
  display: block;
  width: 100%;
  height: 90%;
}

figcaption:before {
  content: "";
  border-top: 10px solid transparent;
  border-right: 10px solid transparent;
  border-bottom: 10px solid #fbfbfb;
  border-left: 10px solid transparent;
  position: absolute;
  top: -20px;
  left: 20px;
}
```

```html
<figure>
  <p><img class=scaled src="https://www.nastol.com.ua/pic/201712/1920x1080/nastol.com.ua-260991.jpg" alt="St. Tropez">
    <figcaption>Saint Tropez and its fort in the evening sun</figcaption>
  </p>
</figure>
```

Описание: https://www.w3.org/Style/Examples/007/figures.en.html